# thread locker / sealant for espresso machine maintenance

Tags: espresso-machine, cleaning, maintenance

I have started disassembling my Nuova Simonelli Oscar, for descaling and fixing purposes, I have checked all the electrical section and I am about to start with the hydraulics.

I have seen that all threads are fully locked and sealed with some hard material, I assume I will have to place it back reassembling it. What kind of thread locker / thread sealer / gasket sealer / gasket replacement is that? can I use any that will sustain high temps or it has to be food safe?

Comment: I can't speak from experience but http://www.home-barista.com/espresso-machines/food-safe-loctite-thread-sealer-t19231.html addresses this question. See also http://www.loctite.com.au/3320_AUE_HTML.htm?nodeid=8802650685441

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pretty much every kind of drinking water sealant that you would use in home installations. You DIY–/ Homework–market (I do not know the English word), normally has such stuff. Just make sure it meets three requirements:

1. For drinking water
2. Can be used with boiling, hot water
3. Does *not* harden over time

There is *no* number one choice. I personally used *plastic–fermit* (which is used for home hat water drainages) with success. I do not even need tools to lock down threads, all are just tightened by hand and it opens easily again.

Usually the manufacturers use something that I would recommend to avoid like the devil the water: PTFE/ Teflon. This locks things down forever. One winding too much and you will break your thread when trying to open it.

---

**Edit:** As grease, I can recommend to use silicone. The thing I used on my current machine is by *fermit* again. If it does not get in contact with water, I would recommend using copper paste (for e.g. by Liqui Moly), which can be used up to 1.4k°C. You will need the grease only for the steam wand and hot water outlet. If you are unsure what to buy, search for (German/ DE) *Amaturenfett* or *Hahnfett*, which is safe for hot potable water and is used for bathroom fittings and similar.

Comment: Thanks! could you elaborate a bit about the grease? why do I need it? and should I use normal silicon or silicon grease?

Comment: @eddyce See the edit.